# Calculate expected value of Y=max{X, 1/2} in a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

Random variable $X$ has uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$. Random variable $Y=\max(X, 1/2)$. Calculate the expected value of $Y$.

I have PDF, so:

$f(x) = 1$ for the $x \in [0, 1]$
$f(x) = 0$ for the $x \notin [0, 1]$

Also, I calculated the expected value of $X$:

$E(X) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) x\,dx = 1/2* x |_{0}^{1} = 1/2 $

So I'm not sure how to handle $\max()$. I'm thankful for any tips.

At the side of the questions, while searching for tips I encountered that $\Pr(\max(A, B) \leq x)=\Pr(A \leq x)\cdot \Pr(B \leq x) = x^2$ over uniform distribution, but I can't see why it's $x^2$.

Comment: As for the $x^2$: for uniform distribution $[0,1]$, CDF is $x$ so $\Pr(X<x)=x$. I use this in my answer below too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to this problem. I think the simplest would be to condition on the event that $X$ is smaller than $0.5$ (so $Y=0.5$). Denote this event by $A$.
Clearly, $\Pr(A)=0.5$ and $E(Y\vert A)=0.5$.

Now, given $\overline{A}$, we know that $X>0.5$ and by standard conditioning*, $X$ is uniform $(0.5,1)$ with expectation $0.75$.

$$E(Y)=E(Y\vert A)\Pr(A)+E(Y\vert \overline{A})\Pr(\overline{A})=0.5\cdot 0.5+0.75\cdot 0.5=\tfrac{5}{8}$$

*The conditioning. For $z\in(0.5,1)$, $\Pr(X<z\vert \overline{A})=\tfrac{\Pr(X<z \cap \overline{A})}{\Pr(\overline{A})}=\tfrac{\Pr(X<z \cap x>0.5)}{0.5}=\tfrac{z-0.5}{0.5}$ which is the CDF of a uniform random variable over $(0.5,1)$.